# SqlKata - what happens if part of where clause is null?

Tags: c#, linq, sqlkata

I have a SQLKata query. It's different from vanilla SQLKata because of a wrapper some colleagues have in place.

```
var conditionQuery = new CustomQuery<MyClass>()
            .Select
            (
               s => s.Id,
               s => s.StartTime,
               s => s.CreatedTime
            )
            .Where(w => w.Id == jobs.PersonLinks.FirstOrDefault().PersonId)
            .Where(w => w.StartTime == jobs.PersonLinks.FirstOrDefault().Time)
            .OrderBy(w => w.CreatedTime);
```

My question is, if `jobs.PersonLinks` is null, does `conditionQuery` resolve as null?

Comment: When PersonLinks is `null` this should `throw`. Did you mean to ask about when it's empty?

Comment: @HenkHolterman even empty it would still throw. He's accessing a property too on that line

Comment: i should have added that PersonLinks is initialised as an empty list. so i should really establish if PersonLinks `.Any` before i attempt to assign something to `conditionQuery`, right?

Comment: I guess i could wrap this in an `if(jobs.PersonLinks.Any())`

Comment: That is for the Linq provider to decide, so the only one that can answer this are those collegues (assuming it is Linq).If the provider does it's job correctly, then this should not be executed yet and the `Where` is not a `Func<MyClass, Guid>` but an `Expression<Func<MyClass, Guid>>`, which can be parsed and transformed.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is very little information on the question, I write a general answer.
You can use this.

```
.Where(w => w.Id == jobs.PersonLinks?.FirstOrDefault()?.PersonId ?? -1)
.Where(w => w.StartTime == jobs.PersonLinks?.FirstOrDefault()?.Time ?? new DateTime())
```